# python: how to remove certain characters

Tags: python, string, character

how do i write a function removeThese(stringToModify,charsToRemove) that will return a string which is the original stringToModify string with the characters in charsToRemove  removed from it.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> s = 'stringToModify'
>>> rem = 'oi'
>>> s.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(rem)))
'strngTMdfy'
```

Comment: FWIW this requires Python 3.x.

Comment: @Marius: implementing it in py2k is even simpler. as [docs show the solution for precisely this problem](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: @SilentGhost `maketrans(dict.fromkeys(rem)` will generate error `maketrans()`  accepts two arguments

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> string_to_modify = 'this is a string'
>>> remove_these = 'aeiou'
>>> ''.join(x for x in string_to_modify if x not in remove_these)
'ths s  strng'
```

Comment: you don't need list comprehension there

Comment: Indeed, it's been a long day.

Comment: I'd use 'if x not in set(remove_these)`.

Comment: That would probably re-create the set() every time in the loop.  I'd suggest remove_these = set('aeiou'), only I suspect for 5 characters linear searching may be faster than hashing.

Comment: Actually I did some benchmarks with timeit, then got embarrassed about premature microoptimization and didn't post them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a chance to use a lambda function and the python filter() method. `filter` takes a predicate and a sequence and returns a sequence containing only those items from the original 
sequence for which the predicate is true. Here we just want all the characters from `s` not in `rm`

```
>>> s = "some quick string 2 remove chars from"
>>> rm = "2q"
>>> filter(lambda x: not (x in rm), s)
"some uick string remove chars from"
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
newString = re.sub("[" + charsToRemove + "]", "", stringToModify)
```

As a concrete example, the following will remove all occurrences of "a", "m", and "z" from the sentence:

```
import re
print re.sub("[amz]", "", "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
```

This will remove all characters from "m" through "s":

```
re.sub("[m-s]", "", "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
```

Comment: Regex isn't ideal for character replacement. The regex has to be compiled and executed which makes it slow.

Comment: True, but regex can be compiled if they are going to be re-used multiple times, and they support much more complex replacement operations. In my experience, such convenience often trumps speed considerations in most programming tasks.

Comment: There are many other problems with this suggestion, however, as you'll discover if you set `charsToRemove` to `^x` or `0-9`.

Comment: @Robert Rossney. `re.escape(charsToRemove)` would overcome that problem, in case anyone reads this and wonders. But regexes are still not the best solution to this problem. `str.translate` for the win.